# How to send messages/sms without Twilio phone number

Tags: laravel, twilio

I tried to send a message without a Twilio phone number because we has no intent to get any messages from users. I followed this tutorial written in Ruby https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-sms-without-phone-number-ruby. I search for any similar tutorial written in PHP but to no avail.

Code:

```
public function sendSms(string $message, string $phone)
    {
        $sid = env("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
        $token = env("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
        $messagingSid = env("MESSAGING_SERVICE_SID");
        $twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

        $message = $twilio->messages->create(
            $phone,
            [
                "body" => $message,
                "messaging_service_sid" => $messagingSid,
            ]
        );

        return $message->sid;
    }
```

When this code run, an error occurred saying **[HTTP 400] Unable to create record: A 'From' phone number is required**
I just send messages without expecting them to reply back. How can I do it? Or Do I need to buy one for it to work?

Comment: Please, do not use `env` outside a `config/**.php` file... when you run `php artisan config:cache`, `env` will always return `null`... so please, do use `config` ALWAYS. And, where are you from? See that the blog says it is not available everywhere, so it depends where are you from...

Comment: Okay thanks I will keep it in mind. If I assigned a value (Twilio phone number) to from key, it wouldn't give me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you supply an unknown parameter to the function call. According to this [docs page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-services-php), it should be `messagingServiceSid` instead of `messaging_service_sid`.

So you could should be:

```php
public function sendSms(string $message, string $phone)
    {
        $sid = env("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
        $token = env("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
        $messagingSid = env("MESSAGING_SERVICE_SID");
        $twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

        $message = $twilio->messages->create(
            $phone,
            [
                "body" => $message,
                "messagingServiceSid" => $messagingSid,
            ]
        )


        return $message->sid;
    }
```

Comment: I'm happy to help. If you found this answer helpful, please go ahead and use the "checkmark" button to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the main author of PHP content for the Twilio blog.

From what I understand, a messaging service still requires a Twilio phone number to send SMS from, as covered in [the Messaging Services documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services) just before the table of contents.

I'll write up an equivalent version of the tutorial that you referenced but centred around PHP, during the week, making sure to highlight this point.

Comment: Actually, this is not true. You can have messaging services without a 10DLC (long code) but you need other senders such as a short code, a WhatsApp sender, or a Alphanumeric Sender ID instead.

Comment: Okay noted that thanks.

Comment: If you're interested @LeslieJoe, here's a PHP version of the Ruby tutorial that you referenced in your question: https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-sms-without-phone-number-using-alpha-sender-and-php